# Indent error in python rpg

Tags: python

for class i am making a "day in the life" and i am doing a day in the life of a gladiator. i am having this error:

```
    if inp == "attack":
                  ^
    Indentation Error: unintended does not match any outer indentation level
```

i have tried going through it and fixing all indents but i can't seem to find where the problem is. How do i fix this? also any suggestions for improvements? here is the source:

http://pastebin.com/2RxbdzXw

Comment: What are you using as an editor? You might want to read the Python Style guide - http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation - recommending 4 spaces per indentation level.

Answer (score 3):

Remember that Python uses indentation to signify code hierarchy, e.g. where in a C-like language you'd have:

```
if (....) {
   something
}
```

Python would simply have

```
if (...):
    something
```

Your intendation is totally wonky:

```
                            while turn == 0:
                if inp == "attack":
                rnd1 = random.randint(1,2)
                    if rnd1 == 1:
```

and should be

```
                            while turn == 0:
                                if inp == "attack":
                                    rnd1 = random.randint(1,2)
                                    if rnd1 == 1:
```

Comment: Following lines also have indentation error like line: 251 ` turn = 1` would not fit to any code block.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you indented the `if` by 4 spaces, when you probably intended to use 8.

It is not indented evenly with `if Battle == 0:`

and it is not in your `while player.health ...` block

Answer (score 0):

line 236 should be indented further to be inside the while loop that begins in line 235
line 237 should be indented inside the if clause of line 236

so it should look more like

```
while turn == 0:  # line 235
    if inp == "attack":  # line 236
        rnd1 = random.randint(1,2)  # line 237
            if rnd1 == 1:
```

Comment: If you use editors like PyCharm it would tell you exactly the problem with your indentation. I suggest investing in something like that.